# Form a la izquierda y otro a la derecha

Tags: html, css

Tengo este codigo:

```
<div id="about"  class="container spacer about">
        <h2 class="container spacer about">Documentos de la compañia</h2>  
        <div class="main">
            <div class="login">
                <form  method="post" action="login.php">  
                    <fieldset>  
                        <div>  
                            <input  placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>  
                        </div>  
                        <div>  
                            <input  placeholder="Password" name="pass" type="password" value="">  
                        </div>  
                        <input  type="submit" value="login" name="login" >  
                    </fieldset> 
                    <p>Si aún no tienes cuenta ve al siguiente link <a href="registrarse.php">Registrarse</a></p>
                </form>  
            </div>
            <div class="login1">
                <form  method="post" action="admin_login.php">  
                    <fieldset>  
                        <div>
                            <input placeholder="Name" name="admin_name" type="text" autofocus>  
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input  placeholder="Password" name="admin_pass" type="password" value="">  
                        </div>
                        <input  type="submit" value="login" name="admin_login" >  
                    </fieldset>  
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y lo que quiero de esos dos FORM que contiene que cada uno este a un lado, y tengo este CSS:

```
#main{
width:960px;
margin:50px auto;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}


#login{
width:300px;
float: left;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family:raleway;
border: 5px solid #ccc;
padding: 20px 40px 25px;
margin-top: 70px;
}

#login1{
width:300px;
float: right;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family:raleway;
border: 5px solid #ccc;
padding: 30px 40px 25px;
margin-top: 70px;
}
```

Por F12 tampoco veo que coja el CSS y no se en que momento exacto esta fallando.( si esta linkado con:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" /
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes mal puestos los selectores css.

Para seleccionar un elemento por el nombre de clase debes usar la sintaxis .. El carácter # se utiliza para seleccionar elementos por su id.

El css debería ser:

```
.main{
    ....
 }

 .login{
    ....
 }

 .login1{
    ....
 }
```

**Ejemplo funcionando:**

```css
.main{
width:960px;
margin:50px auto;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}


.login{
width:300px;
float: left;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family:raleway;
border: 5px solid #ccc;
padding: 20px 40px 25px;
margin-top: 70px;
}

.login1{
width:300px;
float: right;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family:raleway;
border: 5px solid #ccc;
padding: 30px 40px 25px;
margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="about"  class="container spacer about">
        <h2 class="container spacer about">Documentos de la compañia</h2>  
        <div class="main">
            <div class="login">
                <form  method="post" action="login.php">  
                    <fieldset>  
                        <div>  
                            <input  placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>  
                        </div>  
                        <div>  
                            <input  placeholder="Password" name="pass" type="password" value="">  
                        </div>  
                        <input  type="submit" value="login" name="login" >  
                    </fieldset> 
                    <p>Si aún no tienes cuenta ve al siguiente link <a href="registrarse.php">Registrarse</a></p>
                </form>  
            </div>
            <div class="login1">
                <form  method="post" action="admin_login.php">  
                    <fieldset>  
                        <div>
                            <input placeholder="Name" name="admin_name" type="text" autofocus>  
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input  placeholder="Password" name="admin_pass" type="password" value="">  
                        </div>
                        <input  type="submit" value="login" name="admin_login" >  
                    </fieldset>  
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hola Asier, bien visto ^^ te edité la respuesta para añadir el ejemplo de que tu respuesta soluciona su problema

Comment: muchisimas gracias siempre me hago un lio de cuanod funciona con "#" y cuanod con ".", ya funciona eprfecto gracias por vuestra ayuda!